# Vimeo Videos will not work on mac, ipad, or iphone in Safari

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad, safari, vimeo

I have an embeddable vimeo player iframe that does not work on iphone, ipad, or mac when Safari is used. The video works on all other browsers and devices.

Here is a example of what I am doing (with a random video):

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/6691519" width="500" height="375" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallow fullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LCPJu/

I must use vimeo iframes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on safari 6.0.5 on Mac, and it worked fine for me in the jsfiddle, did you install any extra security in your browser?

Comment: No, I don't have any extra security. Also I am using 3 different devices and it seems not to work on any of them.